# Adding tikz pictures on top of a beamer slide

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, positioning, overlays

What is the best practice for adding/uncover TikZ pictures on top of a beamer slide?
I have tried the following approach

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Testing}
  \begin{itemize}
  \item<1-> A
  \item<2-> B
  \item<3-> C
  \item<4-> D
  \end{itemize}
  \begin{picture}(0, 0) {
     \onslide<2>{
       \put(0,30){
         \begin{tikzpicture}
           \draw[black,thick,<->] (0,0) -- (1,0) node {Line 1};
         \end{tikzpicture}
      }}
     \onslide<3>{
       \put(20,100){
         \begin{tikzpicture}
           \draw[black,thick,<->] (0,0) -- (3,2) node {Line 2};
          \end{tikzpicture}
     }}}
   \end{picture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

of wrapping the TikZ pictures in a `picture` environment at the bottom of the slide. However, the picture environment still occupies space on the slide, affecting the positioning of the other elements on the slide.

Also if, I add a new item to the list, I have to recalculate (by trial and failure) the position of the `picture` environment.

Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: What do you want to achieve here? Take a look at `overlay` (the TikZ picture doesn’t occupy any space) as well as `remember picture` (which makes it possible to reference the page as a node itself).

Comment: Looks like `tikzmark` is going to be your friend: http://tex.blogoverflow.com/2013/04/beware-the-tikzmark-my-son/

Answer (score 2):

Would this be what you have tried to achieve? Gradually showing how to to draw via tikz.
Here only the last page is shown. Drawing starts from slide 3 to 5 where `uncover` commands are used.

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix, shapes, arrows, positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Testing}
\begin{columns}
\column{0.5\textwidth}
  \begin{itemize}
  \item<1-> A
  \item<2-> B
  \item<3-> C : draw line 1. 
  \item<4-> D : draw line 2.
  \item<5-> E : draw line 2
  \item<6>  F
  \end{itemize}
\column{0.5\textwidth}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\uncover<3->{\draw[black,thick,->] (0,0) -- (2,0) node[right] {Line 1};}
\uncover<4->{\draw[black,thick,->] (0,0) -- (3,2) node[above] {Line 2};}
\uncover<5->{\draw[black,thick,->] (2,0) -- (3,2) node[below right] {Line 3};}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```